# jQuery function won't run when removed from context

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code has the behavior I want, but I want the behavior to also occur when the page initially loads:
(jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1px1t57s/ )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_repeat_type').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value == 'NR')
      {
        $("#repeat-options").hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#repeat-options").show();
      }
    });
});
```

My first thought was to use "change load" or "change ready" instead of just "change", but this didn't change the behavior (possibly because the function is already wrapped in $(document).ready?)

My next thought was to pull the function out and run it separately as well as on change, but when I removed the function, it broke the existing functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/1px1t57s/1/

What am I missing?

Comment: I see no reason why it would when the page loads

Comment: using  $("#repeat-options").hide(); before the change listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `.change()` to call `change-handler` initially

Note that `toggle` with `Boolean` could be used to `show/hide` elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggle_options() {
    $("#repeat-options").toggle(this.value != 'NR');
  };
  $('#id_repeat_type').on('change', toggle_options).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/tasks/19" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  <br>

  <label for="id_task_name">Task name:</label>
  <input style="width: 100%" id="id_task_name" maxlength="400" name="task_name" type="text" value="sample task" />

  <label for="id_repeat_type">Repeat type:</label>
  <select id="id_repeat_type" name="repeat_type">
    <option value="NR" selected="selected">No Repeat</option>
    <option value="IA">Repeat After X Days</option>
    <option value="IE">Repeat Every X Days</option>
  </select>

  <div id="repeat-options">
    <label for="id_repeat_days">Days between instances:</label>
    <input id="id_repeat_days" name="repeat_days" type="number" />
  </div>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: This works, and I learned several useful tricks from it, thank you!

Comment: @CharlotteMays – I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the change event of the select on document.ready as following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_repeat_type').trigger('change');

    $('#id_repeat_type').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == 'NR')
        {
            $("#repeat-options").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#repeat-options").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified javascript, based on your fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    toggle_options();
    function toggle_options() {
      if ($('#id_repeat_type').val() == 'NR')
      {
        $("#repeat-options").hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#repeat-options").show();
      }
    };
    $('#id_repeat_type').on('change', toggle_options);
});
```

This will create a function, and run it first. There was a typo in the `if` statement. Also, when you call the function in `on('change',toggle_options)`, do not include the brackets (i.e. NOT `toggle_options()`)